# Query que suma las tablas y guarda un valor

Tags: sql, sqlite, sqlite3

quiero hacer un query que sume los valores de las columnas, y luego que esos valores se guarden como una tupla mas de esa tabla.

```
CREATE TABLE "balance" (
"id"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
"cuenta"    TEXT NOT NULL,
"debe"  REAL NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
"haber" REAL NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
"deudor"    REAL DEFAULT 0,
"acreedor"  REAL DEFAULT 0,
"activo"    REAL DEFAULT 0,
"pasivo"    REAL DEFAULT 0,
"negativo"  REAL DEFAULT 0,
"positivo"  REAL DEFAULT 0,
PRIMARY KEY("id")
```

)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te sugiero algo así:

```
INSERT INTO balance
  (cuenta, debe, haber, deudor, acreedor,
  activo, pasivo, negativo, positivo)
SELECT 'Cuenta_auto',
       SUM(debe),
       SUM(haber),
       SUM(deudor),
       SUM(acreedor),
       SUM(activo),
       SUM(pasivo),
       SUM(negativo),
       SUM(positivo)
  FROM balance;
```

En MySQL funcionaría, no sé si será compatible con SQLite.

Inserta previamente algún dato en la tabla para que no la rellene de NULL